# Why std::thread lacks basic features?

Tags: c++, multithreading, std, api-design, stdthread

In `std::thread`:

- No stack size on thread creation.
- No thread priorities.

Why? What's the use of such API?

It's the very base of thread concept.

Stack size, why we don't care about memory? Maybe authors assume only Linux and Windows with paged memory and 64-bit address space, but what about platforms without paged memory?

Priorities, how to make any system with predictable timing without priorities?

Comment: Typical ISO problem.  The larger the api, the harder it is to make everybody equally unhappy.  The thread::native_handle() function is your do-it-yourself backdoor.

Comment: AFAIK, paged memory and 64-bit address space have nothing to do with thread stacks, and thread priorities don't give you predictable timing.

Answer (score 8):

Because *every* platform has to provide the API. You can still have a C++ implementation that targets a platform that *doesn't have threads*.

Because "the stack" is an implementation detail. What does it mean to increase the size of something that doesn't necessarily exist?

What does it mean to change a priority when there *isn't* a priority?

C++ targets an abstract machine. An implementation maps that abstract machine onto a target machine (which may *itself* be abstract). The standard tries very hard to not limit implementations in areas it doesn't have to.

What `std::thread` *does* provide is an (extremely implementation defined) [`native_handle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/native_handle). This fully authorises you to do implementation defined things in implementation defined ways.

Answer (score 2):

> No stack size on thread creation.

Where in the C++ standard are you required to even have a stack on your machine? I believe the answer is: nowhere.

> No thread priorities.

Where in the C++ standard is your machine required to have thread priorities? In fact, I doubt you even need to have any hardware support for threading to be a target platform for C++.

> Why? What's the use of such API?

As @HansPassant indicates - different entities, including hardware vendors, compiler designers and operating systems designers, are involved in considering and commenting on language standard proposals, directly and indirectly. The less you put in an API, and the less you assume the hardware provides, the easier it is to get your proposed addition to the language to be accepted (whether it be by majority vote, concensus, or something more complex).